# Can eclipse show suggestions of words containing the symbols I inputted in the middle of the word

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there any way to make Eclipse show suggestions of words containing the symbols I inputted in the middle of the word. I'm used to this feature in FlashDevelop. For instance class Foo has the method drawCircle, I type "foo.cir" and see the suggestion "drawCircle". Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I have never used FlashDevelop so am unfamiliar with the feature exactly. But I do not believe eclipse has what you are describing natively. However, Eclipse does have a phenomenal add-on library, have you had a search through this for the functionality you require?

Comment: It's really hard to formulate the search query, which I need.